# Python pyside6 Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-imaging-library, pyside6

when i run  my application crashes, sometimes takes multiple screenshots, sometimes not, but crashes every time, I use Mac air m1 8GB ram.

without starting the app the screenshot process works perfectly.

I'm trying to run pure Python threads but the result is the same.

this is code for screenshot i trying make screenshot random during 10 minutes

```
import logging
import os
import random
import threading
import time
import screeninfo
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer, QObject, Signal, QThread

from core.config import APP_LOCAL_FOLDER
from observer.main import Observer, Subject
from helpers.time import get_random_seconds
from helpers.main import check_png_file


class ScreenshotWorker(QObject):
    screenshot_signal = Signal()

    def __init__(self, subject):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_screen = None
        self.timer = None
        self.subject = subject
        self.screenshot_time = get_random_seconds() * 1000

    def run_taker(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.capture_screenshots)
        self.timer.start(self.screenshot_time)
        logging.info(f'Screenshot will be taken in  {self.screenshot_time / 1000}ms...')

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def capture_screenshots(self):
        logging.info(f'Screenshot will be taken in  {self.screenshot_time / 1000}s...')
        folder_name = 'screenshot'
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(APP_LOCAL_FOLDER, folder_name), exist_ok=True)
        screens = screeninfo.get_monitors()
        monitor = self.subject.monitor()
        if monitor == 'active':
            self.active_screen = True
        else:
            self.active_screen = False
        for i, screen in enumerate(screens):
            if screen.is_primary == self.active_screen:
                screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(screen.x, screen.y, screen.width, screen.height))
                self.save_screenshot(screenshot, monitor)
        self.screenshot_time = get_random_seconds() * 1000

    def save_screenshot(self, screenshot, monitor):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        filename = f"screenshot_{monitor}_{timestamp}.png"
        filepath = os.path.join(APP_LOCAL_FOLDER, 'screenshot', filename)
        screenshot.save(filepath)
        logging.info(f'Took screenshot for {monitor} monitor...')
        if check_png_file(filepath):
            self.set_border_image(filepath)

    def set_border_image(self, border_image_path):
        app = self.subject.get_app()
        app.header.setStyleSheet(self.get_stylesheet(border_image_path))

    @staticmethod
    def get_stylesheet(border_image_path):
        # Construct and return the stylesheet with the provided border image path
        stylesheet = f"#header{{\n" \
                     f"    border-radius: 5px;\n" \
                     f"    border-image: url({border_image_path});\n" \
                     f"}}\n" \
                     f"\n" \
                     f"#frame{{\n" \
                     f"    border-radius: 5px;\n" \
                     f"    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 102);\n" \
                     f"    border-image: none;\n" \
                     f"}}\n" \
                     f"\n" \
                     f"QPushButton{{\n" \
                     f"    border: none;\n" \
                     f"    background-color: none;\n" \
                     f"    border-image: none;\n" \
                     f"}}\n" \
                     f"QLabel{{\n" \
                     f"    border-image: none;\n" \
                     f"}}"
        return stylesheet


class ScreenshotTaker(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ScreenshotTaker, self).__init__()
        self.subject = None
        self.worker = None
        self.screenshot_time = 10

    def run(self):
        self.worker = ScreenshotWorker(self.subject)
        self.worker.run_taker()
        self.exec_()

    def stop(self):
        if self.worker is not None:
            self.worker.stop()

    def update(self, subject: Subject) -> None:
        self.subject = subject

        if subject.get_status():
            self.start()
        else:
            self.stop()
```

Comment: Sorry but questions on StackOverflow should always be self-contained and external resources are not allowed for code, as they may be unavailable to some users or could even change or become unavailable, thus making your post invalid. Please take your time to [edit] your question and provide a proper [mre]. Also consider running your program in a terminal, as IDEs sometimes are not able to provide the full debug/traceback of error, especially when using mp or external libraries.